# Sympy: Drop terms without a specific variable

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, linear-algebra

I'm trying to compute some (a lot) of multivariate conditional densities (i.e., the multiplication of several multivariate probability density functions). I'm able to set up and expand the matrices properly but now would like to drop terms that, for example in the equation (and code) below, don't contain *wg*. With help from the posted answer, I was able to develop a hacky solution; improvements are welcome.

UPDATE: MWE

```
import sympy as sym
from IPython.display import display as disp
N  = 211
wg = sym.MatrixSymbol('w_g', N, 1)
wg_n = sym.MatrixSymbol('w_gn', N, 1)
Z_wg = sym.MatrixSymbol('Z_wg', N, N)

# pdf wg
pdf_wg = ((wg - wg_n).T * Z_wg.I * (wg - wg_n))
pdf_full = sym.expand(pdf_wg)
# pdf_full.collect(wg) # NotImplementedError: noncommutative scalars in MatMul are not supported.


# print (wg in pdf_full.atoms()) # False

# this gives what I want
terms = pdf_full.as_terms()[0]
for term in terms:
    if 'w_g,' in str(term[0].atoms()):
        disp (term[0])
```

UPDATE 2: More Complex MWE

Here I'm trying to grab just the terms with b in them.

```
import sympy as sym
from IPython.display import display as disp, Math

mu   = sym.symbols('mu')               # mean non GIA SSH trend
N    = 211
vec1 = sym.MatrixSymbol('1', N, 1)
u    = sym.MatrixSymbol('u', N, 1)     
Pi   = sym.MatrixSymbol('Pi', N, N)    
b    = sym.MatrixSymbol('b', N, 1)

wg = sym.MatrixSymbol('w_g', N, 1)     
wm = sym.MatrixSymbol('w_m', N, 1)     
bhat = mu*vec1 + wg + wm + u # convenience

pdf  = sym.expand((b - bhat).T * Pi.I * (b-bhat))
terms      = pdf.as_terms()[0]
good_terms = [] 
for term in terms:
    if b.args[0] in term[0].atoms():
        good_terms.append(term[0])

print ('Good terms:'); disp(sym.Add(*good_terms))
```

UPDATE 4: Solved
For more complex expressions adding `doit()` to the expand will prevent a bunch of extra loops (e.g.):

```
pdf  = sym.expand((b - bhat).T * Pi.I * (b-bhat)).doit()
```

More information can be found in the comments to the various answers.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You haven't shown the code that you tried with `match` but it should be able to handle this if you expand and then collect.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to collect (see error in updated post). pdf_full.match('w_g') and pdf_full.match(sym.Wild('w_g'))) return None and all the terms, respectively.

Comment: Could you explain whether or not your second update generates the expected output?

Comment: Yes. The output following 'Good terms:'  is the desired output.

Comment: I would like to flatten the terms and subtract the terms I don't want. In more complex expressions repeatedly nest the loops to check the term. Perhaps I should start a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the [`atoms`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.atoms) of the expression and test whether the variable is among them:

```py
from sympy import symbols

a, b, mug = symbols('a b mu_g')
expr1 = a * b + a * mug
expr2 = a * b
for expr in [expr1, expr2]:
    if mug in expr.atoms():
        print(expr, 'contains', mug)
    else:
        print(expr, 'does not contain', mug)
```

PS: An update for your new question. For a `MatrixSymbol` the symbol is stored as `wg.args[0]` (`args[1]` and `args[2]` are the dimensions):

```py
import sympy as sym

N  = 211
wg = sym.MatrixSymbol('w_g', N, 1)
wg_n = sym.MatrixSymbol('w_gn', N, 1)
Z_wg = sym.MatrixSymbol('Z_wg', N, N)

pdf_wg = ((wg - wg_n).T * Z_wg.I * (wg - wg_n))
pdf_full = sym.expand(pdf_wg)

print (wg.args[0] in pdf_full.atoms()) # True
```

Note that the hacky solution is the question could go wrong when `w_g` would be the last item or another name would end in the same string.

Comment: this didn't work as I'd hoped but I was able to get to a hacky solution with it, thanks!

Comment: thanks, the wg.args[0] addresses the issue you raised at the end there. I can't figure out how to make this see the terms that are left. Iterating over the atoms doesn't have the information. I need to see what's leftover so I can do the rest of the manipulations by hand. Sorry I should have asked a clearer question at the outset.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the terms not containing `wg` like:

```
In [53]: pdf_full.subs(wg, ZeroMatrix(N, 1)).doit()
Out[53]: 
    T     -1     
w_gn ⋅Z_wg  ⋅w_gn
```

Then you can subtract those from `pdf_full`:

```
In [54]: pdf_full - pdf_full.subs(wg, ZeroMatrix(N, 1)).doit()
Out[54]: 
   T     -1         T     -1           T     -1    
w_g ⋅Z_wg  ⋅w_g -w_g ⋅Z_wg  ⋅w_gn -w_gn ⋅Z_wg  ⋅w_g
```

Comment: Thanks @OscarBenjamin, this nicely addresses the question. Unfortunately, my equations are more complex than the one I posted, resulting in some nested sums that make this answer not work. I've posted a more complex MWE, perhaps you could take a look? Very much appreciated.